# AutoHotKey - Bulk email filtering script not working fully

Tags: autohotkey

So I currently have the following code:

```
f2::
SendInput, ^c
RegExMatch(clipboard, "[\w-_.]+@(?:\w+(?::\d+)?\.){1,3}(?:\w+\.?){1,2}", email)
WinActivate, emailaddresses - Notepad
SendInput, %email%`r
return
```

It seems to be working, but I'm trying to get it so that if I highlight 5 email addresses it will send them each to a different line in the emailaddresses - Notepad window.

Comment: Can you post the list of email addresses, as you would see them when highlighting?  Just replace the username with something else.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the delimiter, you can use StringSplit and run your function over it.

from http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/StringSplit.htm

```
f2::
SendInput, ^c
;put your delimiter here, assuming space/tab for now
StringSplit, txtArray, clipboard, %A_Tab%%A_Space%
Loop, %txtArray0%
{
  copyemail(txtArray%a_index%)
}
return

copyemail(sTxt) {
  FoundPos := RegExMatch(sTxt, "[\w-_.]+@(?:\w+(?::\d+)?\.){1,3}(?:\w+\.?){1,2}", email)
  if (FoundPos > 0) {
    WinActivate, emailaddresses - Notepad
    SendInput, %email%`r
  }
}
```

see sample above, not tested!